# Set title onSubmit based on current SELECT OPTION VALUE - react

Tags: reactjs

I found this tutorial on how to create a react quizz app on youtube [link to tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEtZ040fsD8)

I am trying to set the title based on the current Select Option Value when submitting the form.
Currently I managed to change the title only when a different option is selected.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";

import FlashcardList from "./components/FlashcardList";

function App() {
  const [flashcards, setFlashcards] = useState([]);
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("General Knowledge");

  const categoryEl = useRef();
  const amountEl = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://opentdb.com/api_category.php").then((res) => {
      setCategories(res.data.trivia_categories);
    });
  }, []);

  function decodeString(str) {
    const textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textArea.innerHTML = str;
    return textArea.value;
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios
      .get("https://opentdb.com/api.php", {
        params: {
          amount: amountEl.current.value,
          category: categoryEl.current.value,
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        setFlashcards(
          res.data.results.map((questionItem, index) => {
            const answer = decodeString(questionItem.correct_answer);
            const options = [...questionItem.incorrect_answers, answer];
            return {
              id: `${index} - ${Date.now()}`,
              question: decodeString(questionItem.question),
              answer: answer,
              options: options.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5),
            };
          })
        );
      });
  }

  function getTitle(e) {
    setTitle(e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form className="header" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="category">Category</label>
          <select id="category" ref={categoryEl} onChange={getTitle}>
            {categories.map((category) => {
              return (
                <option value={category.id} key={category.id}>
                  {category.name}
                </option>
              );
            })}
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="amount">Number Of Questions</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            id="amount"
            min="1"
            step="1"
            defaultValue={10}
            ref={amountEl}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <button className="btn">Generate</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <div className="container">
        <h1 className="title">{title}</h1>
        <FlashcardList flashcards={flashcards} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[Code](https://github.com/Marius-Adam/react-quizz-app/blob/master/src/App.js)

[Live demo](https://marius-adam.github.io/react-quizz-app/)

Comment: Why would you want to set the state when the same option is selected, since state already stores the correct value?

Comment: I set the initial state to "General Knowledge" because otherwise there is nothing showing without selecting an option. State will be set to an empty string once I find out how to set the title on submitting the form

Answer (score 0):

You can set the category as soon the categories are fetched. Can just use the zeroth element to set the title.

```
useEffect(() => {  axios.get("https://opentdb.com/api_category.php").then((res) => {
  setCategories(res.data.trivia_categories);
  setTitle(res.data.trivia_categories[0]);
});
}, []);
```

Comment: setTitle(res.data.trivia_categories[0].name); I added .name in order for this to work. This solved setting initial state to "General Knowledge", however what I am asking is how to set the title based on what is selected once the Generate button is clicked